# How to define permissions for a created file in a job in Databricks?

Tags: permissions, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a job that writes a csv file. The written file has 640 permission, but I would need a file with 770 permissions. Is it possible that job would automatically create a file with 770 permissions so one wouldn't have to manually fix the permissions?

Comment: Which operating system / distro do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are writing the CSV file to.

Without any knowledge about your job, I'll assume you're writing to either the DBFS or file system on the master node of your cluster. In either case, you can add a shell command to your notebook with the %sh magic command and then use 'chmod'.

Ex.

Command 1

```
dataframe.write.format("csv").save("myfile.csv")
//or
dataframe.write.format("csv").save("dbfs:/<some_path>/myfile.csv")
```

Command 2

```
%sh

# for local files on the master node
chmod <options> ./myfile.csv

# for files in the DBFS
chmod <options> /dbfs/<some_path>/myfile.csv
```